# (Mac OSX) Quick Look stopped working as the default music player on Mac OS X

Tags: quicklook

I used to be able to press play on most audio files, and QuickLook would bring it up in less than a second and allow me to preview the file faster than any other program, so it was very convenient, but one day i think while i was using logic 10, Quicklook know longer works, it pops up when i press space bar over an audio file, but it does'nt play anything, please help me figure out the fix!!!

Comment: MacBook-Pro-2:~ $ qlmanage -p something
Testing Quick Look preview with files:
 something
[WARNING] Unable to determine UTI for something -- file:///Users//: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “something” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=something -- file:///Users//, NSFilePath=/Users//something, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9c95c95370 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
[WARNING] Unable to determine UTI for something -- file:///Users: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260

Comment: Would you like to add that to your question, where it can be legibly formatted? ctrl/k [yes, ctrl, even on Mac] will format 'as code', preserving the line breaks etc